# How to submit the Ionic frame work form in Laravel 5.2 controller using post request

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

This my ionic view

```
<form name="Profileform" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="row  row-center">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <div class="hero" style="background-image: url('img/profile-bg1.jpg');">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url(http://203.193.173.125:8001/assets/images/{{userprofile.image}});"></div>
                    <h3><a class="light">{{userprofile.name}}</a></h3>
                    <h4>{{userprofile.mobile}}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-center">
        <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Mobile No:</span>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" ng-model="userprofile.mobile" required readonly >
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="userprofile.name" required >
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="userprofile.email" >
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">DateOfBirth</span>
                <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" ng-model="userprofile.dob" >
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Address</span>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address" ng-model="userprofile.address" >
            </label>
            <lable class="item">
                <span class="input-label" >Gender</span>
                <ion-radio name='gender' ng-model='userprofile.gender' value="0" ng-checked ='userprofile.gender =="0"'>Male</ion-radio>
                <ion-radio name='gender' ng-model='userprofile.gender' value="1" ng-checked ='userprofile.gender =="1"'>FeMale</ion-radio>
            </lable>

            <lable class="item">
            <!-- {{userprofile.classification}} -->
                <span class="input-label" > Classfication </span>
                <ion-radio class="ink" name='classification' ng-model='userprofile.classification' value="employee" ng-checked ='userprofile.classification =="employee"'>employee</ion-radio>
                <ion-radio class="ink" name="classification" ng-model='userprofile.classification' value="bussiness" ng-checked ="userprofile.classification == 'bussiness'" >bussiness</ion-radio>
                <ion-radio class="ink" name="classification" ng-model='userprofile.classification' value="others" ng-checked ="userprofile.classification == 'others'">others</ion-radio>
            </lable>
            <lable class="item">
                <span class="input-label" >Interests</span>
                <ion-checkbox  ng-repeat="interest in userprofile.interests" ng-checked="interest.checked =='true'" ng-model="interest.checked">{{interest.name}}
                </ion-checkbox>
            </lable>
            <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive ink">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>      
</form>
```

Angular controller

```
$scope.submit = function()
 { $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://203.193.173.125:8001/updateprofile',           
         data:$scope.userprofile
         }).success(function (response)
          {console.log(response)
         });
}
```

Laravel middleware cors

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'ACCEPT, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Custom-Header, X-Auth-Token',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age'=> 1728000
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }
    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;    
}
```

I have initialized my cors in kernal.php

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

In my laravel routing

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){      Route::post('/updateprofile',          'Mobile\RotaryIndiaController@updateprofile');
```

}

```
public function updateprofile(Request $request)
    {
             $data =$request->all();
             print_r($data); 

    }
```

I getting issue when from submitted :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://203.193.173.125:8001/updateprofile. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://203.193.173.125:8001' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://10.90.90.145:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Any once can help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: are you running on browser or real device?

Comment: In browser only i am checking

Comment: it will work on real device. and if you want to test in browser you can install corse plugin in chrome for temp solution

Comment: Yes its working fine in real device . I need to check in browser . I installed cros  ' https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/blob/master/readme.md  ' still I am getting same error and  not working in real device also.

Comment: you can install chrome extension

Comment: ok , Thank's  for your response